# On compactness of weak closure of a subset in a locally convex space

Tags: functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a complete Hausdorff locally convex topological vector space, let $X''=(X',\beta(X',X))'$ be its standard bidual. Let $\sigma(X,X')$ be the weak topology on $X$ and let $\sigma(X'',X')$ be the weak* topology on $X''$.

Let $A$ be an absolutely convex (=balanced+convex) closed subset of $X$ such that its $\sigma(X'',X')$-closure in $X''$, that is, $\overline{A}^{\sigma(X'',X')}$ is compact in $(X'',\sigma(X'',X'))$. 
Is it true that the weak closure $\overline{A}^{σ(X,X')}=A$ is compact in $(X,\sigma(X,X'))$?

I think that this should be true since $(X,\sigma(X,X'))$ is a topological subspace of $(X'',\sigma(X'',X'))$. But I am unable to verify this. Can any body give a clue, or a hint, or an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The unit ball of $c_0$ is weakly closed but not weakly compact. Its closure  in the bidual is the unit ball of $\ell^\infty $ which by Alaoglu is weak$^\ast$ compact.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that the space $c_0$ is a good source of counter-examples.

Comment: Any non-reflexive Banach space would work here.